# Is there any ready solution to communicate between web servers interrally?

Tags: python, rest, nginx, tornado, high-load

I have a bunch of different `RESTful` services running, and they designed to be as much separate, as possible (physically or logically). But sometimes they need to communicate with each other (if available). A long as they are web servers, I use http to deliver messages from one to another, and receive response.

The question is, is `http` as a protocol is quite efficient at that? As far as every request requires a new connection, I am concerned for another solution, ready for high-load.

Another thing, say I have 10 instances of services A and only 5 instances of B, and there's an internal load balancer, so when A asks B, balancer gives him the most available B. From that point, I have doubts, if `keep-alive` might help here.

Is there a production-ready library for this? Something similar to `pub/sub`, when service publishes request, and some free service from certain group processes it, and gives the response? Or, say, when service B pulls service A, the B desires to stick around A for a while for few more request, then searching for the free one.

**UPD.** I am using `tornado` framework (python), with `nginx` as load balancer (and plan to use Amazon in future).

Sorry if that question is too broad.

Thank you!

Comment: This question is kinda too broad. Could you narrow it by adding the server and the technologies you are using?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Sorry, updated the question.

Comment: There are at least three distinct questions it this one. You may get a better response, when you divide it in specific ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigations, I've found `RabbitMQ` to be the solution for my problem. It comes with broker, and powerful administration tool.

[image: RabbitMQ]

Using [RPC](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) I've implemented an asynchronous request-reply pattern through [JSON-RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification), so internal services may communicate with each other pretty fast. Multiple instances of same service may be attached to the broker, and requests go round-robin.

Also, [this](http://augustl.com/blog/2013/zeromq_instead_of_http/) article helped me to find the idea about how to do that.